# Possible to create x amount of objects with a while function?

Tags: object, while-loop

If I were to create a new Turtle object I would simply write `Turtle t1 = new Turtle(w,4,4);`.

But lets say I want to create 100 Turtles, can I do it with a while function? I thought I could do something similiar to this:¨

```
int x =scan.nextInt();
while(x>0){
        x--;
        Turtle x = new Turtle(w,4,4);
        }
```

I thought that the turtles would be named what the variable x had for number, but its trying to name them all to x I guess so it doesnt work..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can.

Make sure you keep the references to the x different objects you created. Otherwise you wont be able to reference them again.

```
int x = scan.nextInt();
Turtle[] turtles = new Turtle[x];
while(x>0){
        x--;
        Turtle turtle = new Turtle(w,4,4);
        turtles[x] = turtle;
        }
```

After this you can use any of the x turtles by referencing them:

```
turtles[23].doSomething(param);
```

Your original code won't work because you used the same name for the int typed variable and wanted to use the x also for the Turtle reference. That won't work since the x name is already in use for something else.

Comment: This answer spared me making a new question. Thank you!